# Functions digest is NOT treated the same as a directory of function files!

Tags: zsh

I have a function that uses `zcompile` to create a digest like so:

```
function fpath-setup {
  local FLATFPATH="${TMPPREFIX}-${ZSH_VERSION}-fpath.zwc"

  function {
      typeset -a zarr

      blacklist=('ztodo' 'zed')
      blacklist="^(${(j:|:)blacklist})"

      setopt LOCAL_OPTIONS EXTENDED_GLOB

      for fp in "$fpath[@]"; do
        local ztail=(${zarr:t})
        for it in "${fp}/"$~blacklist; do
          if [[ -z "${ztail[(r)${it:t}]}" ]]; then
            if zcompile "${TMPPREFIX}-try-zcompile" "${it}" &>/dev/null; then
              zarr+="${it}"
            else
              echo "CANNOT COMPILE: ${it}"
            fi
          else
            echo "DUPLICATE: ${it}"
          fi
        done
      done

      zcompile "${FLATFPATH}" "$zarr[@]"

      zcompile -t "${FLATFPATH}" 'compinit' '_complete' || {
        print "Important functions missing from ${FLATFPATH}" >&2
        return 1
      }
  }

  if (( $? )); then
    print "The fpath is left unchanged." >&2
    return 1
  else
    fpath=("${FLATFPATH}")
  fi
}
```

At the point this runs, the `$fpath` looks like this:

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.2/share/zsh/functions
```

After this runs, the `$fpath` looks like this:

```
/var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-fpath.zwc
```

As you can see here, the core Zsh functions are in the digest:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/wgauy

This seems to work fine until I try and use this prompt theme:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/blob/master/pure.zsh#L328

I get the following error at every prompt:

```
vcs_info: configured unknown backend: 'git'
vcs_info: use 'vcs_info_printsys' to find supported systems.
```

This can be resolved by not creating the digest in the first place, or by running the following command before invoking the prompt:

```
autoload -Uz VCS_INFO_get_data_git VCS_INFO_detect_git
```

**So, my questions are**:

1. Is it a bad idea to use `zcompile` on core Zsh
   functions?
2. Why do I need to manually `autoload` some stuff when using the
   `zcompile` digest, but that's not the case when using regular files in a directory?

**Edit**:

I've done some more investigating, and have found that with an `fpath` like:

```
/var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-circuit.zwc
```

The command:

```
prompt pure # ...vcs_info errors
print -f '%s\n' "${(k)functions[@]}" | grep VCS_INFO_get_data_git
```

Returns nothing. However, with an fpath like:

```
/var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-fpath.zwc
/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.2/share/zsh/functions
```

The command:

```
prompt pure # NO vcs_info errors!
type $(print -f '%s\n' "${(k)functions[@]}" | grep VCS_INFO_get_data_git)
```

Returns:

```
VCS_INFO_get_data_git is a shell function from /var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-fpath.zwc/VCS_INFO_get_data_git
```

So, somehow the mere existence of the core directory `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.2/share/zsh/functions` causes the `VCS_INFO_get_data_git` function to be loaded from `/var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-fpath.zwc`.

Does that mean Zsh gives special treatment the core directory? To test that theory, I copy the core function files to a temporary location:

```
cp -r /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.2/share/zsh/functions /tmp
```

Then in a fresh session, with an fpath like:

```
/var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-fpath.zwc
/tmp/functions
```

The command:

```
prompt pure # NO vcs_info errors!!
type $(print -f '%s\n' "${(k)functions[@]}" | grep VCS_INFO_get_data_git)
```

Returns:

```
VCS_INFO_get_data_git is a shell function from /var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-fpath.zwc/VCS_INFO_get_data_git
```

Thus, I must conclude that Zsh is NOT treating it's core directory specially, but instead it is autoloading `VCS_INFO_get_data_git` if a FILE of that name exists in any of the directories on the `fpath`... However, Zsh will still load from the DIGEST if that comes first in the `fpath`.

This is strange.

I haven't seen this behavior documented anywhere, and it's not clear to me how Zsh goes about this (maybe someone that knows Zsh internals can explain).

To try and figure out WHEN autoloading happens, I fiddle with the `fpath` in a fresh session, by changing the `fpath` from:

```
/var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-fpath.zwc
/tmp/functions
```

To remove the `/tmp/functions` directory:

```
/var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-fpath.zwc
```

Then I try changing the prompt:

```
prompt pure
```

Which gives the original `vcs_info` errors, as before:

```
vcs_info: configured unknown backend: 'git'
vcs_info: use 'vcs_info_printsys' to find supported systems.
```

To be sure, the test:

```
print -f '%s\n' "${(k)functions[@]}" | grep VCS_INFO_get_data_git
```

Returns nothing! Now, if at this point I add the `/tmp/functions` directory BACK to the `fpath` again, so it looks like:

```
/var/folders/kb/ydt74z19765cv9vb86rwvcrr0000gn/T/zsh-5.2-fpath.zwc
/tmp/functions
```

The `vcs_info` errors continue to persist!

Can anyone explain what the heck is going on here with Zsh version 5.2?

Comment: Is there some benefit to `zcompile`, or is it just a layer of complexity waiting to mug you?

Comment: @thrig I understand your point about complexity, but this is primarily an experiment. What I'm most curious is, Why does the behavior change? My understanding is this would work just the same as if the functions were sitting the directory in the fpath.

Comment: Why does Zsh automatically resolve functions in a directory on the fpath, but NOT in a digest on the fpath? I can't explain that, but I have figured out that I need to explicitly mark the digest functions for autoloading: `autoload -w "${FLATFPATH}"`. This gets the job done, though I'm not sure why it's not necessary to explicitly mark anything when using just directories and not a digest. Maybe somebody can explain? I thought a functions digest was supposed to be treated the same as a directory of function files.

Comment: Unfortunately marking completion functions like `_ls` for autoload-ing using the `-w` flag to the digest file does not play nice with how Zsh automagically loads it's `_*` completion functions. Zsh just HAS to see an actual real file in the `fpath` somewhere named `_ls` before it is convinced to try calling `_ls` as a completion function. This is very similar to the problem of not autoloading regular functions from digest if they were not also represented as real files somewhere in the `fpath` (which WAS solved by the `-w` flag, but that doesn't solve the special case of completion functions).

Comment: To make Zsh recognize the completion functions in the digest, I am looping through the functions in the digest after `compinit`, using `compdef` to manually register functions starting with an `_`, like this: https://ghostbin.com/paste/7gzc8 ...So at least it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I was researching similar things so I may have a few things that could be useful.

If you do `man zshmisc` and go to the "Autoloading Functions" section is explains a little bit of this. 
    http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html

It says two things here that I"m going to point out

First is that I think one of your issues is you were missing the `-U` flag above:

> The usual alias expansion during reading will be suppressed if the autoload builtin or its equivalent is given the option -U. This is recommended for the use of functions supplied with the zsh distribution. Note that for functions precompiled with the zcompile builtin command the flag -U must be provided when the .zwc file is created, as the corresponding information is compiled into the latter.`

Second is how it autoloads from the fpath variable (I recommend reading the page, but here it is summarized):

`element` is the fpath item, and `function` is the function that's trying to be autoloaded.

There are 3 ways something can be autoloaded.

1. If there's a file called `element.zwc` it will be loaded and searched for functions. (digest). I personally need to research this one more, but you can see what's in a zwc file by using `zcompile -t`. (I know you used this above, just posting it here)
2. If three's a wordcode file (compiled file) named
   `element/function.zwc`
3. The common one which is if it's a file in the fpath (so just
   `element/function`)

Also check out `man zshbuiltins` and look for the man page for `zcompile`. You can use the `-c` and `-a` to compile all functions or all autoloaded functions:
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html

Also you can find another place where the zsh word codes are mentioned if you look up the `.` builtin on the page. You can see specifically if you use it it'll look for the `*.zwc` version of the file and load it instead:

> If a file named 'file.zwc' is found, is newer than file, and is the compiled form (created with the zcompile builtin) of file, then commands are read from that file instead of file.

There's also a function you can autoload called zrecompile that's a little unrelated, but I recommend checking it out. It essentially recompiles your files as needed:

https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/284b5aaeb08f90520ac7dc385e8921471678e7dd/Functions/Misc/zrecompile

Comment: For completion, compdump only looks at those who start with an underscore. You can see that here: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/284b5aaeb08f90520ac7dc385e8921471678e7dd/Completion/compdump#L104